# Getting pandas dataframe from nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and I have not been able to find a good answer for my problem after looking for a while. 
I am trying to create a Pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries.

My list of nested dictionaries is the following:

```
{'category_1': [{'a': '151',
   'b': '116',
   'c': '86'}],
 'category_2': [{'d': '201',
   'e': '211',
   'f': '252'},
  {'d': '-1',
   'e': '-9',
   'f': '-7'}],
 'category_3': {'g': 'Valid',
   'h': None,
   'i': False,
   'j': False},
 'category_4': {'k': None,
   'l': None,
   'm': None,
   'n': None}}
```

And my output should be

```
    a     b    c    d       e       f       g      h     i      j         k    l    m     n  
 0  151   116  86   201,-1  211,-9  252,-7  valid None  False False  None None  None None
```

What i tried,
I'm able to do category 1,3,4 but couldn't figure out the 2nd category
I tried concat and for nested loop to get it

```
ex=pd.concat([pd.Series(d) for d in (eg1)], axis=1).T
```

Then mergiting it.
As i said, couldn't figure out in the whole!

Comment: What you have is a json structure. You can use the `json` package (`load` or `loads` functions) to load it into a dictionary and then write for loops as needed to populate the values in another dict and finally turn that into a DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a short recursive function that returns a series, or a concatenation of several series if one of the keys in your dict (e.g `category_2`) contains a list of multiple dicts.

```
def expand(x):
    if type(x) == dict:
        return pd.Series(x)
    elif type(x) == list:
        return pd.concat([expand(i) for i in x])
```

If I start with the dictionary that you pasted in in your example above:

```
d = {'category_1': [{'a': '151',
   'b': '116',
   'c': '86'}],
 'category_2': [{'d': '201',
   'e': '211',
   'f': '252'},
  {'d': '-1',
   'e': '-9',
   'f': '-7'}],
 'category_3': {'g': 'Valid',
   'h': None,
   'i': False,
   'j': False},
 'category_4': {'k': None,
   'l': None,
   'm': None,
   'n': None}}
```

Then it's just a matter of concatenating all the series created by the recursive method I wrote:

```
output = pd.concat([expand(value) for key, value in d.items()])
```

And merging any duplicate indices so that their items appear in one row and are separated by commas. I also reshape the series into a df with one row and several columns:

```
output = pd.DataFrame(output.groupby(output.index).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))).T
```

This results in a dataframe that matches your desired output:

```
output

    a    b    c   d        e        f       g      h     i        j        k     l     m     n
0   151  116  86  201,-1   211,-9   252,-7  Valid  None  Invalid  Invalid  None  None  None  None
```

Comment: Thanks James! I'm getting a name error while 'concat' d is not defined. Should i create a list d = [] ?

Comment: `d` was the name I gave to the dictionary that you pasted in in your example. I've updated my answer to specify this.

Comment: Ok i changed it, Now it's giving me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Based on your example, my logic expects `d['my_list']` to be a dictionary and not a list. Can you verify that your actual data is identical in structure to your example data.

Comment: Thanks @James i got confused between them, I edited my question accordingly. Should i implement the same logic?

Comment: Gotcha. I just updated my answer accordingly. My code only needed this one update: `output = pd.concat([expand(value) for key, value in d.items()])`

Comment: @JamesDellinger, Nicely summarized +1

Answer (score 1):

The code below recursively tries to flatten the input structure that can have lists or other dicts. When it hit the leafs, adds the content to a flattened dict and then convert it to a dataframe.

```
flattened_dict = {}

def flatten(obj, name = ''):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            flatten(obj[key], key)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for e in obj:
            flatten(e)
    else:
        if obj == 'null':
            obj = None
        flattened_dict[name] = [obj] 

flatten(eg1)
```

The result is:
[image]

Please note that you have to define the null as a string. The definition for the original dict is:

```
eg1 = { 
 "my_list": {
    "category_1": [
        {
            "a": "151",
            "b": "116",
            "c": "86"    
        }
    ],
    "category_2": [
        {
            "d": "201",
            "e": "211",
            "f": "252"
        },
        {
            "d": "-1 ",
            "e": "-9",
            "f": "-7"
        }
    ],
    "category_3": {
        "g": "Valid",
        "h": "null",
        "i": "Invalid",
        "j": "Invalid"
    },
    "category_4": {
        "k": "null",
        "l": "null",
        "m": "null",
        "n": "null"
    }
}
}
```